# Remove CR LF for all lines that are not followed by a specific number

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

I have 14000+ lines of a database, that I want to edit with Notepad++. All these lines should start with 1000 and I therefore want to delete CR LF at the end of those lines that are not followed by 1000.

For example this

```
1000    16  04000 CRLF  
sdfsdf 15 sdf de 05550 CRLF  
1000    16  04000 CRLF  
1000    16  04000 CRLF  
5. sdkfd dksds 16 0555 CRLF  
10/10/14 sdfsdf CRLF
```

should after *Find & Replace* look like

```
1000    16  04000 sdfsdf 15 sdf de 05550 CRLF  
1000    16  04000 CRLF  
1000    16  04000 5. sdkfd dksds 16 0555 10 sdfsdf CRLF
```

I have tried with

- Find what: `\r\n([^1000])`
- Replace with: `_\1`  ("_" indicating a "space")

However, this doesn't seem to remove lines starting with a number (like 5. or 10/10/14). Is it possible to make just one RegEx to find and remove all line breaks that isn't followed by 1000?

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\R(?!1000\b|\z)`
- Replace with:  # a space
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\R              # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
(?!             # start negative lookahead, make we haven't after
    1000\b      # 1000 with a word boundary
  |             # OR
    \z          # end of page
)               # end lookahead
```

**Result for given example:**

```
1000    16  04000 sdfsdf 15 sdf de 05550
1000    16  04000
1000    16  04000 5. sdkfd dksds 16 0555 10/10/14 sdfsdf
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Replace with regex:

`^1000` with `imcrazypotato136476424735746`

`*\r\n` with <kbd>space</kbd>

`imcrazypotato136476424735746` with `\r\n1000`

---

In one regex:

`(\r\n1000)|(\r\n)` with <kbd>space</kbd>`$1`

Don’t ask me how this one works.